# php mysql query - Document is empty when adding more fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this mysql query which runs fine:

```
$query = "SELECT
          USER.USER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, EMAIL, STATUS, PHOTO
          FROM FRIENDLIST, USER, USER_PROFILE
          WHERE FRIENDLIST.FRIEND_ID = ANY (
              SELECT FRIEND_ID FROM FRIENDLIST WHERE USER_ID=".$userID."
          )
          AND APPROVED='YES'
          AND USER.USER_ID=FRIENDLIST.FRIEND_ID
          AND USER.USER_ID=USER_PROFILE.USER_ID
          UNION
          SELECT
          USER.USER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, EMAIL, STATUS, PHOTO FROM FRIENDLIST, USER, USER_PROFILE
          WHERE FRIENDLIST.FRIEND_ID = " . $userID . "
          AND APPROVED = 'YES'
          AND USER.USER_ID=FRIENDLIST.USER_ID
          AND USER.USER_ID=USER_PROFILE.USER_ID";
```

When I add a few more fields in the query I get a *"Document is empty"* error.

```
$query = "SELECT
          USER.USER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, EMAIL, STATUS, PHOTO, gender, cposition, rinterest, about
          FROM FRIENDLIST, USER, USER_PROFILE
          WHERE FRIENDLIST.FRIEND_ID = ANY (
              SELECT FRIEND_ID FROM FRIENDLIST WHERE USER_ID=" . $userID . "
          )
          AND APPROVED='YES'
          AND USER.USER_ID=FRIENDLIST.FRIEND_ID
          AND USER.USER_ID=USER_PROFILE.USER_ID
          UNION
          SELECT
          USER.USER_ID, NAME, SURNAME, EMAIL, STATUS, PHOTO
          FROM FRIENDLIST, USER, USER_PROFILE
          WHERE FRIENDLIST.FRIEND_ID = ".$userID."
          AND APPROVED='YES'
          AND USER.USER_ID=FRIENDLIST.USER_ID
          AND USER.USER_ID=USER_PROFILE.USER_ID";
```

The new fields belong to `USER_PROFILE` table.

Comment: Are these "**" really in your sql code ?

Comment: No...i wanted to make the added fields bold but it placed asterisks instead.

Comment: This is a bit of a mess. Read up on JOIN syntax and start from scratch.

Comment: I tried to do it with join but i got confused

Comment: Do it while confused.It works.

Comment: Yes, but it worth trying. There are different type of jointure and your syntax force a INNER JOIN. So if the "gender" field is null (for example), no result will be returned. You should use LEFT JOIN, which will return information even if gender is NULL (example too).

Comment: Yes but why it works with STATUS and PHOTO fields which belong to the same table and not when i add few more fields from that table?

Comment: If you're confused by explicit JOIN syntax, then implicit (comma-join) syntax can only create more confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `UNION` so both `SELECT` queries **must** have the exact same number of columns. Otherwise your query will fail and that could give errors like the one you see. This error message probably also indicates that the query result is not checked for errors or failures.

This would be much easier to spot if the code were formatted properly. It is allowed (and advised) to use enters inside a SQL query.

Comment: Thanks Arjan!!! That was the problem! I didn't notice that after UNION i had to add those fields in the select statement!